# $.Deferred as member variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

With a background in object oriented languages I'm trying to learn some jquery, and wrap my head around asynchronous calls. My intention was to create a javascript object to contain results of async api calls, and be able to ask said object if it was done loading.

I have been trying to do it using Deferred's from jquery, and I have no problem to get snippets to work as in the documentations examples, but it won't execute in the order I expect when I put the Deferred inside my class.

How do I create javascript objects with $.Deferred as member variables?

(the timeouts in my attached code are to mimic delays in api calls)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
     <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
     <script>
        //top level
        var isdone = false;
        var def = $.Deferred();

        $.when(def).done(function() {
          var msg = "checking topLevel isdone " + isdone;
          console.log(msg);
          $("body").append("<p>" + msg + "</p>");
        })

        var delayedCall = function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            //resolve after 5 seconds
            isdone = true;
            def.resolve();
          }, 1000);
        }
        delayedCall();



        //inside function
        function DelayedObject()
        {
          this.defThis = $.Deferred();
          var defVar = $.Deferred();
          this.delayedObjCall = function()
          {
            setTimeout(function()
            {
              //resolve after 5 seconds
              isdone = true;
              this.def.resolve();
            }, 1000);
          }
          this.delayedObjCall();
          this.getStatusThis = function()
          {
            return this.def;
          }
          this.getStatusVar = function()
          {
            return this.def;
          }
        }

        delObj = new DelayedObject();
        $.when(delObj.getStatusThis() ).done(function() {
          var msg = "checking delObj (this) isdone " + isdone;
          console.log(msg)
          $("body").append("<p>" + msg + "</p>");
        });
        $.when(delObj.getStatusVar() ).done(function() {
          var msg = "checking delObj (var) isdone " + isdone;
          $("body").append("<p>" + msg + "</p>");
          console.log(msg)
        });

        $(window).on("load", function()
        {
          var msg = "<p>" + " Page loaded " + "</p>";
          $("body").append(msg);
          console.log(msg);
        });
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Result

```
checking delObj (this) isdone false

checking delObj (var) isdone false

Page loaded

checking topLevel isdone true
```

Comment: `this.def`, `this.defThis`, `defVar`??? You want *one* deferred.

Comment: I know, I included multiple here to try to illustrate my issue better. Could have mentioned that in a code comment though 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- You refer to the wrong objects/variables in some places (`this.def` does not exist, `this.defThis` and `defVar` are never used)
- `this` is not defined in a timeout callback function (or is `window` in sloppy mode), so you need to use a solution for that (several possibilities, e.g.  `bind`)
- You never resolve `defVar`
- You use one `isdone` variable, so do realise that once it is set to `true` it remains `true` and says little about the other promises.

Here is corrected code (simplified: omitting the change of the document content):

```js
var isdone = false;
var def = $.Deferred();

$.when(def).done(function() {
  console.log("checking topLevel isdone " + isdone);
  isdone = false; // set back to false
});

var delayedCall = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    isdone = true;
    def.resolve();
  }, 500); // Half a second
}
delayedCall();

//inside function
function DelayedObject() {
  this.defThis = $.Deferred();
  var defVar = $.Deferred();
  this.delayedObjCall = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      //resolve after 5 seconds
      isdone = true;
      this.defThis.resolve(); // refer to the correct object
    }.bind(this), 1000); // provide the correct context with bind
    // Also resolve the other deferred:
    setTimeout(function() {
      //resolve after 5 seconds
      isdone = true;
      defVar.resolve();
    }.bind(this), 1500); //... a bit later
  }
  this.delayedObjCall();
  this.getStatusThis = function() {
    return this.defThis; // return correct object
  }
  this.getStatusVar = function() {
    return defVar; // return correct object
  }
}

delObj = new DelayedObject();
$.when(delObj.getStatusThis() ).done(function() {
  console.log("checking delObj (this) isdone " + isdone);
  isdone = false; // set back to false
});
$.when(delObj.getStatusVar() ).done(function() {
  console.log('checking delObj (var) isdone ' + isdone)
  isdone = false; // set back to false
});

$(window).on("load", function() {
  console.log('Page loaded');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```